# .htaccess redirect all pages beginning with

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble trying to redirect all the page of my old website to the entrance page of the welcome webpage of my new website.

the old pages location in my file directory: /web
All those old pages' names I want to redirect are beginning by: "crbst_"
the destination page: http://caravane-liotard.com/

the .htaccess I created is located at the same place as all the old and new website in the filedirectory
Here is the code I tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch 301 ^/crbst_(.*).html http://caravane-liotard.com/
```

Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: why did you use a code snippet here? Please use block code formatting for non-executable code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use `mod_rewrite`, you have to use `RewriteRule` instead of `RedirectMatch`, so something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/crbst_(.*).html http://caravane-liotard.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Please make sure you have `mod_rewrite` turned on in modules.